# Having trouble getting continuous $u(x,t)$ for $2u_{x}+u_{t}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve the following initial boundary-value problem for the constant-coefficient, first-order wave equation:

> $2u_{x}+u_{t} = 0$, $x>0$, $t>0$
>
> I.C.: $u(x,0)= \begin{cases} x-1, & 0<x<1 \\ 1, & x\geq 1 \end{cases}$
>
> B.C.: $u(0,t)=0$, $t>0$

Since $a = 2$, $f(x) = \begin{cases} x-1, & 0 < x < 1, \\ 1, x \geq 1\end{cases}$, $g(t)=0$, the solution is given by

$\displaystyle u(x,t) = \begin{cases} f(x-2t), & x>2t \\ g\displaystyle \left(\frac{2t-x}{2} \right), & x < 2t \end{cases}$.

I figured out that the solution, then, must be $u(x,t) = \begin{cases} 0, & 0 < x < 2t\\ (x-2t)-1, & 2t < x < 2t+1 \\ 1,& x > 2t + 1 \end{cases}$

(Unless I am incorrect in the solution, in which case, please correct me!)

Now, what I am having trouble with is the second half of what I am asked to do for this problem, which is to graph $u(x,t)$ as a function of $x$ for $t =0$, $t = 1$, and $t = 2$.

Quite frankly, what is bothering me is that what I get for $u(x,0)$, $u(x,1)$, and $u(x,2)$ are not continuous, so I must be making a mistake somewhere:

$\mathbf{t = 0}: \, u(x,0) = \begin{cases} 0, & x=0 \\ x-1, & 0<x<1 \\ 1,& x>1 \end{cases}$ which is not continuous at $x=0$ or $x=1$.

$\mathbf{t=1}: \, u(x,1) = \begin{cases} 0, & 0 < x < 2 \\ x-3, & 2 < x < 3 \\ 1, &x>3 \end{cases}$ which is not continuous at $x = 2$ or $x=3$.

$\mathbf{t=2}: \, u(x,2) = \begin{cases} 0, & 0 < x < 4 \\ x-5, & 4<x< 5 \\ 1, & x> 5\end{cases}$ which is not continuous at $x=4$ or $x=5$.

Now, it is my understanding that the solution $u(x,t)$ is supposed to be continuous, and I don't understand what I am doing wrong!

Please help! And if possible, could you give me a straightforward solution without any hints or questions? I am really in a hurry and don't have time for that right now.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems our I.C. is not continuous so it is not surprising, that te solution is not continuous as well

Comment: The initial conditions for $u$ are not continuous so why would you expect that $u$ is continuous? The wave equation does not regularize

Comment: @GregordeCillia weird. I did not notice that. So, the solution is supposed to be this way?

Comment: Or @Matt or Gregor, is this not the correct way to solve a first-order equation with IC's that are not continuous?

Comment: There's an error in the problem: what's the value of $u(0,0)$? Is it $-1$ or $0$? Solve it for $u(x,0) = x  \ 0\leq x \leq 1$

Comment: @Luca can you fix your LaTeX?

Comment: I'm trying to say that $\ u(0,0) = -1 \ $ in I.C. and  $\ u(0,0) = 0 \ $ in B.C. So, maybe they meant that I.C. should be  $\ u(x,0) = x \ $ in the first part

Comment: @Luca honestly, I have no idea. I'm going to try to get to campus early to go ask my professor, because this problem is driving me batty (very apropos for Halloween!)